# Modelsim log progress to output file

Tags: tcl, modelsim

I'm running Modelsim to do a long simulation. I want to have an ouput like this for my progress report to be logged in a file:

```
Mon Oct 29 21:05:57 IRST 2018   Section 1 
Mon Oct 29 21:05:57 IRST 2018   Section 2 
Mon Oct 29 21:05:57 IRST 2018   Section 3
...
```

I want to have a tcl script to create this output and log it in a file during simulation progress.
I have below TCL code snippet:

```
set fp [open mylog.txt w]
puts $fp "Section 1"
close $fp
```

It will print label `Section 1` inside file `mylog.txt`.
However I don't know how to print current system date and time to this file from modelsim command line (TCL).
using `date >mylog.txt` will print date/time to file however since file is open, it will make thing corrputed and output format wouldn't be nice like what I described above.
Are there any methods to print system data/time to file inside TCL scripts?

Comment: Try to see if `puts $fp "[clock format [clock scan now]] Section 1"` is satisfactory to you. You can futher more alter the timestamp format per the manual [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/clock.htm#M18)

Comment: `clock scan now` is a very costly way to do exactly the same as `clock seconds`. On my machine it takes 60.9 µS versus 0.48 µS for `clock seconds`

Comment: @SchelteBron Good point. Not sure where I picked up that bad habit :)

Comment: @Jerry please put your comment as answer here, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command [`clock`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/clock.htm) for various purposes involving datetime manipulation. To get the current timestamp, you can use `clock scan now` (slower) or `clock seconds` (faster, credit to [Schelte Bron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7994192/schelte-bron) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051055/modelsim-log-progress-to-output-file#comment93002494_53051055)) then `clock format` to format it from epoch format; for example:

```
puts $fp "[clock format [clock seconds]] Section 1"
```